# create ios7 button on prior versions

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uibutton

Is it possible to create `button` to be like one in `ios 7` on prior versions of `ios`? I want my `button` just to show text, and not to be white rectangle or blue when selected.

Comment: try `UIButtonTypeCustom`.

Comment: You'd need to use images of iOS 7 buttons in earlier versions of iOS. Check for the iOS version and replace existing buttons with the images in case not iOS 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Interface builder then just drag a button in to the view and in the Attributes inspector select type as custom and just add the required text in the placeholder. 
Else if you are creating buttons programatically then

```
UIButton *buttonName = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[buttonName setTitle:@"Some Text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 3):

try this ...

```
UIButton * btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[btn setTitle:@"text" forState:UIControlStateNormal]
```